# Why did Descartes believe the physical world was determined?

Tags: descartes

What justification does he give for the idea that everything in the physical world is determined?

Comment: Some reference to Descartes' works ?

Comment: See [Descartes' Physics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes-physics/#LawsMotiCartConsPrin): Descartes' physical world is ruled by *Laws*: "It is obvious that when God first created the world, He not only moved its parts in various ways, but also simultaneously caused some of the parts to push others and to transfer their motion to these others. So in now maintaining the world by the same action and with the same laws with which He created it, He conserves motion; ... 1/2

Comment: ... not always contained in the same parts of matter, but transferred from some parts to others depending on the ways in which they come in contact. (*Pr.* II 62)". 2/2

Comment: The world as created by God is necessarily organized so as not to deceive human intelligence; Descartes maintained that God would not deceive this intelligence. Whether this makes them also 'determined', I'm not sure. CS